# Ubuntu Server 18.04 does not boot in legacy mode in Lenovo SR650 Server

Tags: system-installation, uefi, 18.04, lenovo, bios

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 in legacy mode in Lenovo SR650 Server. If I only insert 1 harddisk during installation and do the installation everything works fine but when all the disks are inserted the OS doesn't boot. When I try installing the Ubuntu Server 18.04 with all 16 disks inserted, installation completes successfully but later I am dropped to initramfs during reboot. How do I fix it?

Comment: I have created a custom ISO with it which only supports legacy mode.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What exactly happens when "the OS doesn't boot"? What happens when you turn on the computer and select the Ubuntu installer as the boot medium? At which point does the boot process hang? What do you see on the screen when it does? What do you see on the screen before it hangs? Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: The OS installs correctly but after reboot I am dropped to initramfs shell :)

Comment: Can you try my solution here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1070130/699864

Answer (score 0):

I have one machine that will only install with one hard drive in it. Then I shut it down, insert the other disks and boot into the bios and set the installed disk first in the boot order , otherwise it will not boot.